# "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been using Eclipse to build Android applications, and have been testing them on my HTC One X. I had the drivers installed from HTC Sync, and Eclipse is up-to-date. Recently, this connection simply stopped working. The computer (running Windows 8 Pro 64-bit) detects the One X, and I can view the files on it from my computer. However, Eclipse does not see the phone when I go to run the application, and whenever I plug in my phone with Eclipse running, I get this error:

```
[2013-07-09 14:47:43 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2013-07-09 14:48:15 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
```

Furthermore, the HTC sync manager tells me that my phone is locked and that it cannot retrieve information from it, despite the fact that the phone is unlocked. I have tried to reset ADB, and that did not work. Debugging is enabled on the phone. How would I go about fixing this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if you have two versions of adb installed.  Eclipse installs one and perhaps HTC Sync installed another.  They might be different versions.  You'll have to do some path trickery to get both apps to use the same version of adb.

You can search for ADB in your path by entering the following in a command prompt:

```
where adb.exe
```

Comment: How would I go about checking this? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: you'll have to search through your folders for adb.exe; you can limit your search to where the apps are installed.

Comment: Nope. Only one version of ADB on the computer.

Comment: Good guess, I had same problem. I removed Android Studio I've installed yesterday and everything started working :)

Comment: I have only one adb.exe and still problems; may be android studio is directly referencing it's on internal adb. It'll be tough to figure.

Answer (score 0):

i do very sample solution for this just delete .android folder and close android studio and restart android studio