# Can we have Two adb sessions for single connected device vi USB?

Tags: android, debugging, adb, appium

Can we have two adb sessions to the device connected via USB port?

If yes. How can we start another adb session when there is another session currently active and running..

Answer (score 5):

No, we cannot. We can have one ADB server connected to multiple devices. But not one device connected to multiple ADB Servers at any point of time.

Also, how to you plan to insert two micro usb cables (or whichever works on your device) onto one device? **It is also physically (in terms of hardware) not possible if you are talking about adb servers on different computers.** You could think of WIFI and USB adb connections at the same time, but to my knowledge it is not possible as of today.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353756/unable-to-get-the-elements-in-uiautomator-tool-when-the-app-is-running-on-the-de

Comment: i am facing the issue with my test setup where if I launch  the  app from my Web Gui application the current running adb session is getting closed. Can you have a look at the above mentioned stackoverflow issue for details of my problem.

Comment: can we have single server with 2 different sessions with the adb server?

Comment: In my project i am using the adb to establish the session btw my webapplication and device. Now I am using the same adb server instance to launch the appium. But, the issue is I am unable to establish the another connection to the device with the same adb server.

Comment: adb server is out of date.  killing...
error: could not install smartsocket listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037:
etwork address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
could not read ok from ADB Server
 failed to start daemon 
error: cannot connect to daemon
-------------------------------------------------------------------
this is the error i m getting when i m trying to establish connection to the device..

Comment: There are a couple of solutions to this error [on this discussion](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184713)

Comment: @AndroidMechanic In adb version 1.0.36 and android version 6.0.1 **it is possible to have 2 instance of adb one via wifi and other via USB**. It may be possible that we can have one more adb instance via bluetooth though not tested yet.